# Expression Blend 4.0 Path.Fill isn't working

Tags: windows-phone-8, expression-blend-4

Given the following Path I would expect the resulting diamond shape to get filled with red but it doesn't. Am I missing something here?

```
<Path Data="M59.351001,42.182 L30.783001,84.351998 M0.75000094,43.78 L30.783001,84.45 M59.351,42.182 L29.318001,0.74999998 M0.75000094,43.78 L29.318001,0.74999998" 
        Margin="254.7,207.333,325.199,187.467" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FFA91515" StrokeThickness="1.5" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" Fill="#FFFF2300"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have just drawn four straight lines that happen to look like they form a closed path, while they actually don't. If you use the *Direct selection tool*, you can actually drag these lines around.

How do I know this? You have four Ms in `Data`. An M denotes the start of a new line.

You will need a closed path to be able to "fill" it. Try using the *Pen* tool instead to create a closed path.